# Simple inline alignment of text and image in html

Tags: html, vertical-alignment

I have the following:

```
<h5 class=""><strong>Buenos Aires</strong> <img style="height: 18px;" src="./files/uploads/flags/Argentina.png"/> </h5>
```

where I put the height to 18px because that's the height of the text in `h5`. However, I get the following image:

[image]

I'm trying to align an image with text, and I found some solutions but they're all quite complicated. I was wondering if the alignment can happen just inline without writing CSS.